# How to avoid repeats of Javascript events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io, jquery-events

I'm new in JS and I have some difficulties with the using events. 
 
My problem is that the event is repeated more than once. I use socket.io for my simple game. Here is my code:

```
socket.on("permit", function(){
    $('#attack').on('click', function(){
        var id;
        $('#game-field').on('click', '.cell', function() {
            id = parseInt(this.getAttribute('id'));
            $('#game-field').unbind('click');
            socket.emit('attack', id); /*when event repeats - that line creates problems like a snowball*/
        });
    });
});
```

How can I avoid unnecessary repetitions of events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  **[one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)**  selector to bind the event at one time .it ll works only one time

```
  $('#attack').one('click', function(){
         // your code
});

  $('#game-field').one('click', '.cell', function() {
           // your code
});
```

OR

```
socket.on("permit", function(){

    $('#attack').off('click', attecked);
    $('#attack').on('click', attecked);
});

function attecked(){
        var id;
        $('#game-field').one('click', '.cell', function() {   // dont unbind the event removed ur code  $('#game-field').unbind('click');
            id = parseInt(this.getAttribute('id'));
            socket.emit('attack', id); /*when event repeats - that line creates problems like a snowball*/
        });
}
```